# How to transfer covariance-like table into one-to-one pairs cleverly in stata?

Tags: stata, data-manipulation

I encounter a practical issue on data management using Stata. What I'm planning to do is creating variable of spherical distances between 30 province capitals (so there are roughly 870 identical values) of China. There have been some user-written commands to handle this issue(through google map) but My problem is, for some confidential reason, the data is stored in a isolated computer that disconnected to internet,so I have to defined all of the one-to-one distance value in do-file and then merge them into the data. Given the nontrival workload (though not really infeasible), I wonder if there is some clever way to do the job. I have an excel worksheet in which the distance is  like a covariance martrix with province capitals' names appearing in both first row and column,it's like a lower-triangle matrix, . stands for values

```
      A         B          C           D            E                     AD           
            capital_1  capital_2  capital_3  capital_4    ······    capital_30
1 capital_1 
2 capital_2    '
3 capital_3    '           '
4 capital_4    '           '           '
  ········

  capital_30   '           '           '         '
```

I know how to import such martrix, but can I generate the desired one-to-one pairs? Thank you.

Comment: Can --reshape-- be useful ?

Comment: Yes. Did you try? What problem did you have, if any?

Comment: Only to reaffirm: a standard `reshape long` should work here. Report back if you have problems with that. If so, please show us some code with your attempt and a clear description of the problem.

Comment: Thank you for your kindly remind, Roberto. I'm learning the syntax of `reshape` right row. Before actually implement it, two possible difficulties come into my mind. First one is my row name is  chinese character (province capital name), the name capital_# is just for illustrative purpose here(I don't think pull a brunch of chinese characters in the example is meaningful, but they are in real data), so as you can see it's far from  well-organized like inc80,inc81,inc82 in the stata example. The second one is

Comment: the data structure I deal with is a lower-triangle matrix, not a balanced panel (or symmetrix matrix) so when I use command `reshape long`, I may obtain missing values from the upper-triangle part. I hope I can pose the picture of the real data structure but my reputation is not sufficient

Comment: In fact, I can rename the row name to a more regular series like city_1 city_2 to deal with the first problem and fill up upper-triangle part of the data matrix to solve the second.It's merely 30 names any way. But how about 300 names. I want to figure out if there is some general approach

Comment: See `help rename group` for "batch" renaming. The missings you can `drop` later, **after** the `reshape`; so I wouldn't worry about that. `reshape` should be general enough. I don't see how more variables will restrict you; the limit for number of observations (relevant because you are going from _wide_ to _long_) is quite large. See `help limits`. Like I said before, feel free to post code with a serious attempt.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for @Roberto 's helpful suggestion, I have partly solved the problem, and I pose my solution to benefit any newcomer who may meet similar problem, and  want to benefit from the real experts to improve my code

```
//import data from excel file
import excel using distance.xls
*********************************
* rename the variable name
* (to make it more well orgnized to facilitie use of --reshape-- command
*********************************
* rename the first column
ren A id
* rename the following variables
local i=0
foreach var of varlist B-AF {
    local j=`i'+1
    local i=`i'+1
    ren `var' distance`j'
}

*********************************
* reshape the data
*********************************
reshape long distance,i(id) j(city)
tostring city,replace
***the following part is really urgly, because I don't know how 
*to gen a one-to-one mapping between orginal province name and
*the new generated variable name like distance`j',I have to recover
*them by hand, I hope someone can help me to improve this part**
replace city="北京" if city=="1"
replace city="天津" if city=="2"
replace city="河北" if city=="3"
replace city="山西" if city=="4"
replace city="内蒙古" if city=="5"
replace city="辽宁" if city=="6"
replace city="吉林" if city=="7"
·····
```